# Suggestion for React Native

Tags: react-native

Greetings!! I am developing an app with React Native. Which uses chroma key functionality for live streaming or video recording. I failed to find any ready library or plugin. As well as could not find any ready code to help me.

If you have any suggestion for it then do let me know. It would be a great help

Regards

Comment: Please keep the question very precise to what you actually want. **"Suggestion for React Native"** is not the correct question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use the live streaming function, you can use `WebRTC` technology.
The appropriate `react-native` library address is as follows.

[react-native-webrtc](https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc)